# What is the in built function for converting from text to FLOAT in Excel (similar to INT())

Tags: excel-formula

What is the in built function for converting from text to FLOAT in Excel (similar to INT())

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`VALUE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/value-text-HP010062583.aspx)

Oh well. This answer is apparently too short. Is it not now?